# Guarantees for waitpid() after epoll() from pidfd

Tags: linux, unix, posix, epoll, waitpid

I am writing a process manager that monitors its` child processes and restarts them if necessary.

Currently, I have `pidfd` associated with every running process and `epoll` waiting for all of these `pidfd`s. When one process terminates, `epoll_wait()` wakes up, and to determine the exit code of the process, I use blocking `waitpid()` to determine my process` exit code (in my program it is necessary to determine, whether to restart the process or not).

I was wondering, whether there are any underlying problems with my solution, as I have to make my process manager as lock-free and safe as possible. My main concern is using `waitpid()` after `pidfd` becomes readable. Is it possible that this wait will lock my execution?

I would appreciate any help, insight, or feedback regarding my concern.

Comment: Use a non-blocking `waitpid()` and try again later if it returns 0?